# Clarification about Borel $G$-homology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

I'm starting reading something about $G$-homology and as one of the first example I encountered the Borel $G$-homology defined as $$ H^G_*(X):= H_*(EG\times_G X)$$
where $H_*$ is any homology theory, (let us stick with singular homology theory for now).

As one of the first properties one want to prove is that if $X$ is a free $G$-space, then $$H_*^G(X)\xrightarrow{\cong} H_*(X/G)$$

Now on [these notes](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/somnath/Notes/EH.pdf) just after Def. $2.2$, the author want to prove this, but **it seems to me** that he is assuming that the $G$-action on $EG$ is *globally* transitive, (i.e. $BG=\ast$) which it's not true in general.

On [this book by Lück and Kreck](https://books.google.de/books?id=nBY3n1Q8nUwC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=borel%20equivariant%20homology%20induction%20structure&source=bl&ots=AKXMOuBcxb&sig=MGgnJLwqjIkd0MU0vPw1V-S60qg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAj5O8yZLLAhUmMJoKHRZIDgAQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=borel%20equivariant%20homology%20induction%20structure&f=false) , in example $20.8$ they suggest (in a slightly more general setting) to apply the induction structure, which in our easy case would be associated to the trivial morphism $\pi\colon G\to \{1\}$ and would become $$\phi\colon EG\times_G X \to E\{1\}\times_{\{1\}}\{1\}\times_{\pi} X$$ $$ (e,x)\mapsto (E\pi(e),1,x)$$
and then using the easy fact that $E\{1\}\simeq \ast$ we would have $$\phi \colon EG\times_G X \to X/G$$

They claim that since $G$ acts freely on $X$, the map induces an isomorphism in homology. Now I'm aware that sometimes this is taken as an axiom for equivariant homology theories, but I need a proof in my easy case.

**UPDATE** Maybe I found a way to correct the reasoning done in the notes, So it is sufficient to prove that $$\phi\colon EG\times_G X \to X/G$$ is an homotopy equivalence. Let us consider the contraction of $EG$ to a point, which exists by def. of $EG$. So we have an equivalence $EG\times_G X\xrightarrow{\simeq} * \times_G X$ and the latter should be the same as $X/G$. **What is unclear** to me is where the free action on $X$ comes into play here.

Comment: If G does not act freely that map is not an equivalence (modding out by G doesn't preserve equivalences, which is basically the reason for doing the borel construction anyway). Instead, note that when G acts freely the map from X to the orbits is a fiber bundle with fiber G. It follows that your map is a fibration with fiber $EG\times_G G \cong EG$ which is contractible, so the map is an equivalence in this case.

Comment: @DylanWilson I see your point. Ok, so every doubts boil down to see why $EG \times_G X \to X/G$ is a fibration. My first attempt was to consider the fibrations $X\to X/G$ and $EG\to *$, and then "glue them together as a map $X\times EG \to X/G$, but I don't see how to go to $\times_G$

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I spoke too soon- I still think it's homotopy fiber is G but maybe that's not so elementary, so a different tactic: There is a fiber bundle $EG\times X \rightarrow EG\times_GX$ and this maps to the quotient map of X by G. The fiber of both maps over a point is just G and a map of fibrations which is an equivalence on fiber and total space also induces an equivalence on bases.

Comment: Ok let me recap. You basically want to consider a commutative square (map of fibration?) where the top row is $EG\times X \xrightarrow{\pi_2} X$ which is indeed an equivalence, and the lower row is $EG\times_G X \xrightarrow{p} X/G$ which is what we want to prove that it is an equivalence. Vertical arrows are the fibrations right? 

So in order to conclude one has to use the result you mentioned. Could you give me some reference to it? since I never seen it and I'm curious now

Comment: It's in any standard algebraic topology book. Here's the proof: fibrations give long exact sequences in homotopy groups, and maps of fibrations induce maps of long exact sequences. Now use the five lemma. (With a bit of fuss near pi_1 and pi_0, I guess)

Comment: $5$-lemma... Completely forgotten about that! That's amazing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with your argument about extending a homotopy of $EG$ to $X\times_G EG$, why should you be able to do that? In the non-free case stuff can happen... Just to imagine, consider $gx=x$, $ge\neq e$ and the image of a path $e \to ge$ in $EG$.

What you can *always* do is write down a map $X\times_G EG \to X/G$ by collapsing $EG$ to a point. This is an often use method to compute equivariant homology e.g. by considering spectral sequences. Also you will see that equivariant homology is a lot about analyzing the fix points of the action, something which only exists for non-free actions. However if $X$ is $G$-free, then the fiber computes to $EG$, which gives you a weak equivalence if your $X$ was paracompact to start with.

Comment: ok, what you say makes sense, still I don't see why $X\times_G EG \to X/G$ is a fibration, which i think is what you implicitly used to get the weak equivalence right? Maybe I'm missing something in your answer:)